# Tensorflow Module Import error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.nn' has no attribute 'rnn_cell'

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-import, attributeerror, recurrent-neural-network

When attempting to pass my RNN call, I call tf.nn.rnn_cell and I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.nn' has no attribute 'rnn_cell'
```

Which is odd, because I'm sure I imported everything correctly:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But looking at the docs, things have moved around between tensorflow versions.

what would you all recommend to fix this??

Line, I'm getting the error against:

```
state_per_layer_list = tf.unstack(init_state, axis=0)
rnn_tuple_state = tuple(
    [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(state_per_layer_list[idx][0], state_per_layer_list[idx][1])
     for idx in range(num_layers)]
)
```

Specifically:

```
tf.nn.rnn_cell
```

I'm using anaconda 3 to manage all of this so, the dependancies should all be taken care of. I have already tried working around a damn rank/shape error with Tensor shapes which took ages to resolve.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `tf.nn.rnn_cell` with `tf.contrib.rnn`

Since version 1.0, `rnn` implemented as part of the contrib module.

More information can be found here
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.rnn

Comment: Cheers that seemed to resolve the issue.

you got an idea on how to handle this for the following: 

states_series, current_state = tf.nn.rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)

Comment: I receive an error saying no attribute RNN for it: 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.nn' has no attribute 'rnn'

Comment: but when I use contrib.rnn I get another error saying: 

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: try this `tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn`

Comment: Cheers, that worked with a bit of fuss I got it working.